# How to work out if a file has been read in order to read the next file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnDisplayOrderDetails_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                         ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                         Handles btnDisplayOrder Details.Click

  Dim myStreamReader As StreamReader
  Try
    myStreamReader = File.OpenText("Textfile1.txt")
    Me.txtOrderDetails.Text = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
  Catch exc As Exception
  Finally
    If Not myStreamReader Is Nothing Then
      myStreamReader.Close()
    End If
  End Try

 If txtOrderDetails.Text = "" Then
   Dim mystreamreader1 As StreamReader
   Try
     mystreamreader1 = File.OpenText("textfile2.txt")
     Me.txtOrderDetails.Text = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
   Catch ex As Exception
   Finally
     If Not myStreamReader Is Nothing Then
       mystreamreader1.Close()
     End If
   End Try
 End If

End Sub
```

What I would like this code to do is:

Read the first Text file upon button click, then when I've cleared the text Box (with the use of a different button which is already coded) I would then like to read in the second text file upon button click into the same Text box as before.

Comment: VB6 and VBA are very different to VB.Net. Are those tags really relevant?

Comment: You know it's finished when it returns. You code also makes no mention of a list of files. Can you provide a more complete sample or more information on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hint: You will need to put your sample code in a loop and call it once for each file you want to read. :)

Comment: i can give you move code if you need sorry about that i wasnt aware of the difference im using microsoft visio 2010 so i assume the coding language is in face VB.net

Comment: also Olle would you mind putting this in an example so that i can understand what your trying to say this is my interpretation of what you just said

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the files.  Combine them all into a single text box, or does each file belong to a specific textbox.

The looping method to place all the files into a single text box:

```
Dim filePath As String = "C:\Users\Practice\Practice\bin\Debug"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt")
  sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(f))
Next
txtOrderDetails.Text = sb.ToString()
```

Or if it's not a list, then you go through your files one by one:

```
Dim test1 As String = Path.Combine(filePath, "Textbox1.txt")
If File.Exists(test1) Then
  TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(test1)
End If
Dim test2 As String = Path.Combine(filePath, "Textbox2.txt")
If File.Exists(test2) Then
  TextBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(test2)
End If
```

Comment: this has helped but all it does is display 1 Text file to the text box and isnt doing anything for the other files plz help urgent

Comment: @AnthonyKeating Like I said, it wasn't clear what you are actually doing with these files from your post.  That's why I offered two possibilities to try to help.  Try editing your post with more details.

Comment: okay thanx lars ill update what code i have now ive changed it but im not quite getting it